# Best way to handle optional parameter with null value in query

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best way to handle optional parameter if null value is passed in select query in oracle

E.g. `select * from emp where deptno = 10 and empno in (7782,7934)`

In above query, if user will not select any empno then it should fetch all records where deptno = 10

Comment: How (in what form) do you get the user input?

Comment: user can select more than 1 value from dropdown of which datatype will be number

Comment: How your current query will look like when user won't select any of the values?

Comment: @nonsleepr : select * from emp where deptno = 10 and empno in (NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little bit dirty solution for your problem if you just want to instert the value into the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE
    deptno = 10
AND (empno IN (%user_input%,%not_used_value%)
OR   COALESCE(%user_input%,NULL) IS NULL);
```

Here `%user_input%` is a placeholder for values, selected by user and `%not_used_value%` is `empno` id, which is never used.

So, the resulting query could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE
    deptno = 10
AND (empno IN (7782,7934,-999)
OR   COALESCE(7782,7934,NULL) IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I handle this case in the programming environment that is issuing the query.  Within the code, I check for the null case, and then exclude that part of the where clause as needed.  Is that something you can do?

*edit*

If you were using ColdFusion:

```
<cfquery>
select 
  * 
from 
  emp 
where 
  deptno = 10
  <cfif Len(empno)> 
     and empno in (<cfqueryparam value="#empno#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">)       
  </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

(query params added for correctness)

Comment: I can do that but here problem is that, it will be come in IN Clause i.e. multiple values and also one thing if I want to avoid OR clause

Comment: Take a look at my edit - that's an example of how you can do this without having to add any kind of OR to your statement.

Comment: Yes I figured that.  It is just an example - pseudo code , if you will.

Comment: @user1017936 Maybe then you'll post the answer for your question yourself?